# Do Poincaré duality algebras need to be defined over a field?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, duality

I asked the below question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637962/can-we-define-the-notion-of-a-poincar%C3%A9-duality-algebra-over-a-ring) on MSE, but after some time and a bounty offering I have not received an answer.

A graded commutative, connected $\mathbb{k}$-algebra $A$ is called a *Poincaré duality algebra* if it is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{k}$, so that $$A = \bigoplus_{i=1}^d A^i,$$ and the $\mathbb{k}$-linear maps

$$A^i \rightarrow Hom_{\mathbb{k}}(A^{d-i},A^d), \quad a \mapsto \phi_a, \text{ where } \phi_a(b)=ab$$

are isomorphisms.

For example, it can be stated that the cohomology algebra of a manifold is a Poincaré duality algebra.

Every definition that I've seen of a Poincaré duality algebra (for example [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701309.pdf) by Stanley and Lambrechts) assumes that $\mathbb{k}$ is a field. Is this necessary, or just convenient? Is there a problem with simply having $\mathbb{k}$ a ring, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$? Would we then require some additional assumption such as zero torsion?

Comment: I mean, you can always make any definition you want, the question is how useful it is. Over a general ring it's a bit annoying because the condition "the pairing $A^i \otimes A^{d-i} \to \Bbbk$ is nondegenerate" is not equivalent to "$A^i \to \hom_\Bbbk(A^{d-i}, \Bbbk)$ is an isomorphism". What is the motivation behind this question?

Comment: Also your definition is not really the usual one. Usually you have to fix some linear form $\epsilon : A^d \to \Bbbk$ and the isomorphism is $a \mapsto (b \mapsto \epsilon(ab))$. With your definition it's not clear that $A^d = A^0$ for example, just that $A^0 = \hom(A^d,A^d)$ for example. (But again, maybe your applications call for this?)

Comment: As you said, torsion phenomena make it so that $H^*(X;\mathbb Z)$ is not a Poincaré algebra in the above sense if $X$ is a compact oriented manifold. One possible way out is to work in a derived way, i.e. with the chain complex $C^*(X;\mathbb Z)$ and not just its homology; the  resulting notion of a self-dual chain complex (really, a stable infinity category equipped with a "Poincaré structure) is developed in an ongoing lecture by Thomas Nikolaus, although the relevant course notes have not been published yet: https://www.uni-muenster.de/IVV5WS/WebHop/user/nikolaus/Surgery.html

Comment: Thank you for your comments. My motivation lies in understanding some statements regarding the homology/cohomology algebras of "Poincaré duality spaces" - where by this terminology I mean spaces which have Poincaré duality in the sense of manifolds, but which are not necessarily manifolds. One definition in particular defines such spaces to be those for which their cohomology algebras are Poincaré duality algebras in the above sense (without specifying $\mathbb{k}$ a field), but as Bertram points out, if working with the above definition this is only the same if $\mathbb{k}$ is a field.

Comment: You can find an example useful in the context of Koszul homology in definition 1 in https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/glasgow-mathematical-journal/article/ascent-and-descent-of-gorenstein-property/D7E9D1C81352123F2676BFDA7B3DC883